# How to check if a list item is in a 2d array in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi guys I'm trying to check if a particular is list item is in a 2d array in python if that make sense.
below is what I have tried.

```
from numpy import random

x = random.choice(range(0, 9), size=(6, 2))

print([2, 5] in x)
```

This runs but returns the wrong result. It just checks if 2 or 5 is in the 2d array and returns true else false.

for example.. a result from the above code is below

```
 >>>[[6 4]
 [5 5]
 [7 3]
 [5 1]
 [8 2]
 [1 8]]
```

so if I want to be able to check if [1 8] is in the 2d array above and return a true or false. Please any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you are checking for 2nd array:

```
print([2,5] in x[1])
```

However, If you want the same random samples for each execution, you need to apply seed

```
from numpy import random
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(4)
x = random.choice(range(0, 9), size=(6, 2))

print(x)
print(x[1])
print([1,5] in x[1])
```